# How to add array to arraylist in inheritance?

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
class MyArrayList <T> extends ArrayList <T>  {
    // T[]a should receive both integer array and string array
    public MyArrayList (T[] a)
    {   super();
        // This is the problem
        // it does't work 
        //I'm trying to use a new object to add all of the elements in the input array to the MyArrayList object. 

        MyArrayList <T> list = new MyArrayList <T>();
        for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
            list.add(a[i]);    
    }

    public static void print()
    {
         // Display array elements 
         // I don't work it out          
         System.out.println("");    
     }
}

public class TestMyArrayList
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String[] subjects = {"EIE320", "EIE558", "EIE375", "EIE424"};
        Integer[] marks = {90,85,70,80};

        MyArrayList<String> sList = new MyArrayList<String>(subjects);
        Collections.sort(sList);
        sList.print();

        MyArrayList<Integer> mList = new MyArrayList<Integer>(marks);
        Collections.sort(mList);
        mList.print();
    }
}
```

I know the method `ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(array))`, but I'm not sure how to use it in inheritance, or I should use for loop in the code to store?

Comment: Your constructor is adding the values to a separate instance of MyArrayList.  Change `list.add` to `this.add`.

Comment: The main problem is this statement " MyArrayList <T> list = new MyArrayList <T>();"

Comment: Remove that line.  A constructor initializes a new instance.  It should not create a second instance.

Comment: The "[" and "]" in the output can not be deleted?